# Gif на webp из двух и более файлов

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i 1950.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -ss 20 -t 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=8,scale=-2:200" animation.webp
ffmpeg -i 1950.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -ss 40 -t 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=8,scale=-2:200" animation1.webp
ffmpeg -i "concat:animation.webp|animation1.webp" -c copy animation3.webp
```

При попытке объединить 2 гиф файла, выдает ошибку

```
[webp @ 0x487d800] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Возможно ли выполнить данную операцию, по объединению 2 и более WEBP в один файл и сохранить анимацию. И возможно ли за одну операцию, выполнить тоже самое, только не сохраняя результат по файлам animation.webp и animation1.webp

Пробую в два прохода выполнить и на выходе получить один файл, не выходит. Хелп

```
ffmpeg -y -i /1981.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -ss 20 -t 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=8,scale=-2:200" -f null && ffmpeg -i /1981.mp4 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -ss 40 -t 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=8,scale=-2:200" /animation3.webp



Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Filter scale has an unconnected output
```